# Export vertex colors (color attributes) of Protein Model to .usd file to present in Keynote

Tags: export, file-format, vertex-colors

I am a blender beginner and plan use blender to visualise protein structures.
Currently my workflow will be: Protein database >.stl> PyMOL >.gltf> Blender >.usd> Keynote.
This will also be the basis for exporting other scientific models to Keynote in the future and present them to peers.

### The Problem

Annotating the protein structure in PyMOL generates vertex colors (color attributes) on the model, when I export this model as .gltf I can see the annotations in Blender (4.0.2), but when I now try to export it further to .usd I do not find a way to keep the colors (at least they are not shown in Keynote) and the model is plain white.
In my shader nodes I plugged color of "color Attributes" to base color in the "Principled BSDF" node and BSDF to surface in the "Material Output".

What am I missing here?
I checked several forums an could not find a solution to this.
Let me know if you need further information.